# How to count run-lengths of NULL runs in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a primary key `pk` and a nullable column `col`. I want to find consecutive sequences of rows where `col` is `NULL`, ordered in descending order of run-length.

I will accept as a valid answer a query that returns the run-lengths alone, but in the future (perhaps in a separate question) I will want to know some `pk` that points me to either the start or end point of each run.

Example data:

```
pk    col
--    ---
1     'a'
2     NULL
3     'b'
4     NULL
5     NULL
6     NULL
7     'c'
8     NULL
9     NULL
10    'd'
```

Expected query result:

```
runlengths
----------
3
2
1
```

I prefer standard SQL if possible, but this is for analyzing a production data set stored in MySQL, so whatever works best in that context.

Comment: Probably too late to change now, but for future reference it would have been better for you to use a database that supports the standard SQL analytical functions (i.e. pretty much anything apart from MySQL).

Comment: Yup! It was completely out of my control in this case, but for my own projects I will keep your advice in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (
    pk INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    col CHAR(1)
)

INSERT @a (col)
VALUES  ('a'), (null), ('b'), (null), (null), (null), ('c'), (null), (null), ('d')

SELECT COUNT(*) as runlengths 
FROM @a AS A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        l.pk, 
        MAX(r.pk) AS prev
    FROM @a AS l
    INNER JOIN @a AS r
        ON l.pk > r.pk
    WHERE 
        l.col IS NOT NULL
        AND r.col IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        l.pk
) AS B
    ON A.pk < B.pk AND A.pk > B.prev
GROUP BY 
    B.pk
```

It's T-SQL dialect, but I believe it's clear enough.

There is an issue with this query, if first/last row has NULL value, but it is not difficult to fix that. The way how to do that depends on the your requirements.

Comment: It works on my computer, so it would be better if you provide some more information, like input data and script you run. I suppose you've changed something?

Comment: yup its my bad i actually copied your query but didnt change @a it worked fine only order by is missing. i have voted as +1 i have created fiddle using your statement http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e317a/1

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
select count(*) runlengths from (
  select col, @count := @count + (col is not null) cnt
  from t, (select @count := 0) init
) final
where col is null
group by cnt
order by count(*) desc
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71e88/1).